# Why does adding this defensive copy avoid deadlocks?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Here's the original code. This program could end up deadlocking because the `updateProgress` method calls another method that may or may not acquire another lock. And we've acquired those two locks without knowing if it has been done in the right order.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Downloader extends Thread {
  private InputStream in;
  private OutputStream out;
  private ArrayList<ProgressListener> listeners;

  public Downloader(URL url, String outputFilename) throws IOException {
    in = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
    out = new FileOutputStream(outputFilename);
    listeners = new ArrayList<ProgressListener>();
  }
  public synchronized void addListener(ProgressListener listener) {
    listeners.add(listener);
  }
  public synchronized void removeListener(ProgressListener listener) {
    listeners.remove(listener);
  }
  private synchronized void updateProgress(int n) {
    for (ProgressListener listener: listeners)
      listener.onProgress(n);
  }

  public void run() {
    int n = 0, total = 0;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    try {
      while((n = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, n);
        total += n;
        updateProgress(total);
      }
      out.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) { }
  }
}
```

The author of the textbook suggested to change `updateProgress` to create a defensive copy of `ArrayList<ProgressListener> listeners` before iterating through it.

```
private void updateProgress(int n) {
    ArrayList<ProgressListener> listenersCopy;
    synchronized(this) {
      listenersCopy = (ArrayList<ProgressListener>)listeners.clone();
    }
    for (ProgressListener listener: listenersCopy)
      listener.onProgress(n);
```

}

Doing so avoids calling an "alien" method with a lock held and it reduces the time that the original lock, acquired in `updateProgress`, is held. I understand why it reduces the time the lock is held for but not how it avoids calling an alien method with a lock held. Here's my train of thought.

1. It creates a clone of the arraylist `listeners`. This clone is a separate object that contains the exact elements that the original `listener` has.
2. This is thread safe now because what now you have a "local" copy, at least local to that specific thread, and what another thread does to their local copy does not impact you.
3. You update the listeners via the `onProgress` method. However this change is only local to your `listeners` copy.
4. `updateProgress` returns but how do the "local" changes get propagated to "original" `listeners`? Since it's a clone, they're separate objects but how do they communicate their updates back to each other?

That's the part that I'm stuck on.

Comment: Aside: a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` would probably be better here.

Comment: I think all this is doing is mitigating the pathological case where one of the listeners invokes `addListener` or `removeListener` during its `onProgress` implementation.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth but surely that wouldn't have anything to do with deadlock, rather that would cause a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: @AndyTurner - The original code *would* deadlock, I think.  The lock is acquired by entering `updateProgress`, which then calls `listener.onProgress`, which then (pathologically) calls `addListener`, which attempts to acquire the lock.

Comment: Oh, except `synchronized` methods are reentrant.  So I don't understand what problem is anticipated here, after all.

Comment: Instructional simplicity aside, the fact that the textbook author chose an unsafe cast over `new ArrayList<>(listeners)` makes me question the authority and expertise of the book.

Answer (score 4):

A really pathological case would be:

- One of the listeners starts a `Thread`
- That thread attempts to invoke a synchronized method on `Downloader`
- The thread on which the listener is called (the one that started that new thread) calls `join` on the started thread.

Something like:

```
class Pathological implements ProgressListener {
  // Initialize in ctor.
  final Downloader downloader;

  @Override void onProgress(int n) {
    Thread t = new Thread(() -> downloader.removeListener(Pathological.this));
    t.start();
    t.join();
  }
}
```

You'd get a deadlock in this case, because the started thread couldn't make progress whilst the first thread is holding the monitor.

Taking the defensive copy avoids this, because the first thread isn't holding the monitor when `Pathological.onProgress` is called; but I'd still prefer to use an alternative list implementation designed to handle concurrent access, e.g. `CopyOnWriteArrayList`.

Comment: Even more pathological than I was imagining ;)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I believe the only appropriate response is "muhahahahaha".

Comment: Or use the multicaster pattern, which is especially efficient when the number of listeners is small.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The book does not explain that -- the code is from "7 concurrency models in 7 weeks".

Answer (score 0):

The title of your question does not match the question at the end. The title of the question is about avoiding deadlocks, which has been [answered by Andy Turner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48104912/2711488) already. He describes a scenario, how a deadlock may occur, and the conclusion has been given by yourself in the question: you avoid the deadlock by not invoking an “alien method” while holding a lock.

Since this seems to be already understood, your question is actually an entirely different one. You are asking, “how do the ‘local’ changes get propagated to ‘original’ listeners?”

The answer is, there are no such local changes. The 3rd bullet of your list is wrong. The local copy is not only local to the current thread, the copy is local to the `updateProgress` method and not seen by any other code.

So when there are modifications to the listener list made via `addListener` or `removeListener`, regardless of the thread doing the modification, it is directly affecting the list referenced by the `listener` field of your object, which is still the same as before. But this change does not affect the local copy, the `updateProgress` method is iterating over. Since `updateProgress` is only iterating over the local copy, it will never have any modification that would need to be propagated to the original list.

Note that this copy would be even necessary in a single threaded scenario. A lot of `List` implementations, most notably `ArrayList`, do not support being modified while someone is iterating over it, even if the modification is made by the same thread doing the iteration (except for modifying the list through the same `Iterator` used for the iteration, which does not apply here).

Alternatives are the [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html), which does not need to copy when iterating, but when the list gets modified, or the Multicaster pattern, which may only need (partial) copying when removing listeners, but may become inefficient when the number of listeners becomes large (but is *very* efficient for small numbers). See [`AWTEventMulticaster`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/awt/AWTEventMulticaster.html) for an example [implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/awt/AWTEventMulticaster.java) of this pattern.